# How many versions of GTA San Andreas exist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Between the [Hot Coffee controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Coffee_(mod)) in 2005 and the removal of songs in 2014, we know that there have been a couple of revisions and re-releases.

How many versions of GTA San Andreas exist between the different platforms?